# Convert to the day and time of the year in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have data for more than 3 years. For each year I want to find the day corresponding to Jaunary 1 of that year. For example:

```
> x <- c('5/5/2007','12/31/2007','1/2/2008')
> #Convert to day of year (julian date) –
> strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y")$yday+1
[1] 125 365   2
```

I want to know how to do the same thing but with time added. But I still get the day not time. Can anyone suggest what is the better way to find the julian date with date and time ?

```
> x1 <- c('5/5/2007 02:00','12/31/2007 05:58','1/2/2008 16:25')
> #Convert to day of year (julian date) –
> strptime(x1,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")$yday+1
[1] 125 365   2
```

Rather than this result, I want the output in decimal days. For example the first example would be `125.0833333` and so on.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I want the output in decimal days. For example the first example would be 125.0833333 and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you hoping to get the day + a numerical part of a day as output? If so, something like this will work:

```
test <- strptime(x1,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

(test$yday+1) + (test$hour/24) + (test$min/(24*60))
#[1] 125.083333 365.248611   2.684028
```

Although this matches what you ask for, I think removing the `+1` might make more sense:

```
(test$yday) + (test$hour/24) + (test$min/(24*60))
#[1] 124.083333 364.248611   1.684028
```

Though my spidey senses are tingling that Dirk is going to show up and show me how to do this with a `POSIXct` date/time representation.

Here is an attempt of such an answer using base functions:

```
mapply(julian, as.POSIXct(test), paste(format(test,"%Y"),"01","01",sep="-"))
#[1] 124.083333 364.248611   1.684028
```

Comment: Your spidey senses are on fire today

Comment: @ thelatemail : Your senses are spot on. Yes, I think removing `+1` makes more sense as you said. Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` representations along with `firstof` function from `xts`.

```
x1 <- c("5/5/2007 02:00", "12/31/2007 05:58", "1/2/2008 16:25")
x1
## [1] "5/5/2007 02:00"   "12/31/2007 05:58" "1/2/2008 16:25"  


y <- as.POSIXlt(x1, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

result <- mapply(julian, x = as.POSIXct(y), origin = firstof(y$year + 1900))

result
## [1] 124.083333 364.248611   1.684028
```

if you don't want to use xts then perhaps something like this

```
result <- mapply(julian, 
                 x = as.POSIXct(x1, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT"),
                 origin = as.Date(paste0(gsub(".*([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", x1), 
                                         "-01-01"),
                                  tz = "GMT"))

result
## [1] 124.083333 364.248611   1.684028
```

Comment: @geektrader - is there any reason for the gsub/as.date stuff? - I have just added a simpler version to my answer but am curious if I am missing something.

Comment: @thelatemail nope.. just didn't think of it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the other way around (convert day of the year to date and time), you can use this little function:

> doy2date = function(mydoy){
>     mydate = as.Date(mydoy, origin = "2008-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "GMT") 
>     dech = (mydoy - as.integer(mydoy)) * 24
>     myh = as.integer(dech)
>     mym = as.integer( (dech - as.integer(dech)) * 60)
>     mys = round(I( (((dech - as.integer(dech)) * 60) - mym) * 60), digits=0 )
>     posixdate = as.POSIXct(paste(mydate, " ", myh,":",mym,":",mys, sep=""), tz = "GMT")
>     return(posixdate)
>   }

As an example, if you try:

> doy2date(117.6364)

The function will return "2008-04-27 15:16:25 GMT" as a POSIXct.

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.