# Day-of-the-year (1-366) in R

Tags: r, date

I have 20 years of pre-1900 y data specified by year month and day in separate columns:

```
yyyy mm dd y;
```

I want to extract day-of-the-year (1-366) for each row in R please!

Comment: Try `as.Date(paste(dat$year,dat$month,dat$day,sep="-"))`, then consider this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490614/convert-to-the-day-and-time-of-the-year-in-r/15490743 and answers.

Comment: Thanks. I was avoiding Julian days; the term adds confusion because they are not strictly days of the year (1 to 366).!